# Correctly bind a function to Button onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

This is a React-Bootstrap-Button:

```
<Button onClick={console.log('Hello')} className="pull-right">Try me</Button>
```

I want the function to execute everytime a click the button. However, it will execute on pageload. I read somewhere that I should bind the function:

```
<Button onClick={console.log('Hello').bind(null)} className="pull-right">Try me</Button>
```

This gives me the error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `log` immediately and then trying to `bind` its return value (which is `undefined`).

You need to bind the function itself.

You also need to bind it to the `console` context and not the `null` context. `log` cares about the object it is attached to.

```
onClick={console.log.bind(console, 'Hello')}
```

---

[Idiomatic React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) would create the function separately instead of trying to do it inline though:

```
function myFunction () {

  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Hello');
  }

  return (
    <Button onClick={handleClick} className="pull-right">Try me</Button>

  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want:

```
<button onclick="javascript:console.log('Hello');" className="pull-right">Try me</button>
```

Notice `onclick="javascript:console.log('Hello');"`.

Comment: That doesn't play nicely with React, and the label `javascript:` is entirely pointless since there is no loop to apply the label to.

Comment: I noticed that on Firefox it only works with `javascript:`. I don't really know if that is still the case, but it was some time ago... @Quentin

Comment: It has never been the case. Something else must have been responsible for the problem. Perhaps you are sticking it in an `href` attribute.

Comment: Why was it for me then?

Comment: No, I used onclick and without `javascript:` it did not work.